# Graham's scan algorithm including all colinear points

Tags: convex-hull

I'm solving the [Erect the Fence](https://leetcode.com/problems/erect-the-fence) problem on leetcode. My approach is to use Graham's scan algorithm with the following steps:

1. Find the leftmost point p0
2. Sort the points according to their angle relative to p0
3. Iterate over the points:

- while the orientation of the current point and the two last on the stack is clockwise, pop the last point from the stack
- add the current point to the stack

The problem is sorting the points in such a way, that moving away from p0, the nearest points are first, and moving forward p0, the other way round. I cannot find any clean solution to this problem and every proposed solution on leetcode using this algorithm, is somehow wrong.

How to modify Graham's scan algorithm to include all degenerated points (creating the same angle with p0)?
Is it even possible, or should I go for another algorithm?

Comment: After sorting your way, you can "fix" the sort by reversing the suffix of the array consisting of points along the same final ray.

Comment: I thought of this, but the collinear points are not necessary at the end.

Comment: This was under the assumption that you have chosen your base point to be an extreme point (this guarantees that all other points lie in a half plane and thus "sorting" by angle even makes sense). To make the sort well-defined you should have a tiebreaker for equal angles with respect to the base point (e.g. length). Then you can reverse either a prefix or suffix, so that traversal through the array is all clockwise or counterclockwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code, which passes all the tests. It's based on Matthew C's comment.

```
def graham_scan(points: list) -> list:
    p0 = find_leftmost(points)
    hull = []
    points.sort(key=cmp_to_key(lambda p, q: orientation_cmp(p0, p, q)))

    # handle colinear points at the beginning
    i = 0
    n = len(points)
    while i < (n - 1) and get_orientation(p0, points[i], points[i+1]) == 0:
        i += 1
    points[:i+1] = sorted(points[:i+1], key=lambda p: get_distance(p0, p))

    # main loop
    for p in points:
        while len(hull) > 1 and get_orientation(hull[-2], hull[-1], p) < 0:
            hull.pop(-1)
        hull.append(p)

    return hull
```

get_orientation returns -1 for the clockwise orientation of two vectors and -1 for anti-clockwise. get_distance function returns the distance between two points. orientation_cmp is:

```
def orientation_cmp(p0, p, q):
    orientation = get_orientation(p0, p, q)
    if orientation < 0:
        return 1
    elif orientation > 0:
        return -1

    return get_distance(p0, q) - get_distance(p0, p)
```